# Date formatting is off when pulling a date from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

So I have a simple script which fills in a formula when Column B is filled with date. All is fine except that date is showcasing entire timezone format. I've tried using the following way to format date but then immediately the script wont populate anything.

```
urls = Utilities.formatDate(ss.getRange("b2:b").getValue(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
```

FULL CODE :

```
function image()
{
  var ss, urls, formulas;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  urls = ss.getRange('b2:b').getValues();
  //urls = Utilities.formatDate(ss.getRange("b2:b").getValue(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
  //urls.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');

  formulas = [];


for (var i = 0, len = urls.length; i < len; i++)
  {
    var y = "=100*index(GOOGLEFINANCE(\"CURRENCY:USDINR\",\"price\",\"";
    var z = "\"),2,2)";
    if (urls[i] =='') break;
   formulas.push([''+ y +'' + urls[i] + ''+ z +'']);

  }

  ss.getRange(2, 3, formulas.length, 1).setValues(formulas);
}
```

[TEST SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14XSGYeNlCX9SYr9BVIM9eqzKR57ZBzgZ82WPalVB5FM/edit#gid=1151470276)

Comment: missing s (getValue()) in your modified code ?

Comment: tried now but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `getValues();` Use `setNumberFormat()` after `getRange()` immediately, so:

```
var range = ss.getRange("B2:B").setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

[image]

`setNumberFormat` and `getValues` has the same hierarchy in Range object.

Comment: tried it but the log is still showcasing it as full timezone format when executed

Comment: so now it's working, coz u you couldnt even run it before, correct?  but what condition is not being met? im just using your code ; )

Comment: Its only in the log. the output on the sheet is still missing. Anyways for timebeing, I am regexextracting the date from the whole timezone style. well atleast something better than nothing. You can see Sheet3 tab:)

Comment: What's your expected result/output?

Comment: As of now when I execute it, the final output is ...........=iferror(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDINR","price" Wed Apr 26 2017 03:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)),2,2))) ............... but the needed  output is ..................... =iferror(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDINR","price",26-04-2017),2,2)))

Comment: I have a solution in tab1 of the sheet attached above but I got it with too much complexity of regexing the date out of timezone stamp

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.getValues` use `.getDisplayValues`

Comment: Can you please add more detail about your answer, like links to the documentation for example?

Comment: urls = ss.getRange('b2:b').getDisplayValues();